# Ntile function not dividing groups evenly when being ran from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

I have the following code inside a stored procedure.

```
select 
ID,NTILE(2) OVER (Partition by GroupID order by newID()) as RandomSplit
into #TempSplit
from TableA
where IsUpdated = 1

Update a
set a.SplitColumn = CASE WHEN b.RandomSplit = 1 THEN 'A'
                       WHEN b.RandomSplit = 2 THEN 'B' 
                  END
from Table A a
inner join #TempSplit b
on a.ID = b.ID and a.IsUpdated = 1
```

This code works as expected and produces the data table below.

```
  GroupID  SplitColumn

   1       |     A
   1       |     A
   1       |     B
   1       |     B
   2       |     A
   3       |     A
   3       |     B
```

However,when I execute this code from the stored procedure I get the following results

```
  GroupID  SplitColumn

   1       |     A
   1       |     A
   1       |     A
   1       |     B
   2       |     A
   3       |     A
   3       |     B
```

This is sample data but basically what is happening is that when I execute from the stored procedure the groups are not distributed evenly(in the real data the variation is by thousands rather than just one). Not sure what is exactly causing this behavior since again if I execute the code manually it comes up with the correct behavior.
Also I know this is a small sample of what is happening, but its also not happening for all GroupIDs. Meaning GroupID = 3 always gets split correctly into two even groups, while say GroupID = 1 always gets wrongly split.

Comment: I hate to say this, but check the code in the proc. Maybe you forgot the order by newid(). Just for giggles, add option(recompile) on it.

Comment: If you don't show us the stored procedure that reproduces this issue, we can't help you.

Comment: @TabAlleman The only thing the stored procedure has before this statement is Inserting records from other tables into TableA. I don't think this is affecting the behavior of above code.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `#TempSplit` only for the rows where `IsUpdated = 1`.

However, you are joining back to *all* the values.  If `id` is duplicated in `TableA`, then you would get results as you see.

Comment: I see that this was missing, however luckily for me since I was in QA this didn't have the duplicate Ids. I have fixed this and the problem still persists.